# how to add a prefix key to all keybindings of a specific mode?

Tags: key-bindings, keymap, prefix-keys

i am using a mode, but am not used to its key-bindings: some of them conflict to the emacs global ones. so, i want to add a prefix key-binding to all its existing keybindings.

for example, if *my-mode* defines key-binding <kbd>M-]</kbd> for *my-mode-shot*, i am looking for some ways as following:

```
(define-prefix-for-mode 'my-mode (kbd "C-c m"))
```

then the key-binding for *my-mode-shot* now is <kbd>C-c m M-]</kbd>.

how should one add a prefix key-binding to all available key-bindings of a specific mode?

Comment: It can depend on the kind of mode.  Can you give details?

Comment: @Stefan i am looking for a general solution, not a mode-specific one.

Comment: A solution that works reliably for all modes is probably impossible.  You can probably cook up a solution, using the code I provided, which will work for most major modes, tho.

Answer (score 4):

One way to *move* -mode's keybindings could be with something like

```
(let ((origmap <foo>-mode-map)
      (newmap (make-sparse-keymap)))
  (define-key newmap <prefix> origmap)
  (setq <foo>-mode-map newmap))
```

But this code will fail if run before foo-mode is run.  And it will have no effect if run after the mode is entered.  So you'll probably have to do it within `(with-eval-after-load '-mode ...).

Also, if it's a minor mode, the above code won't have any effect either, because you additionally have to do something like (within the above `let`):

```
(setcdr (assq '<foo>-mode minor-mode-map-alist) newmap)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Define a prefix key for the mode's keymap.
2. Undefine the other keys that bother you, from that keymap.

Suppose that mode `foo-mode` binds key `C-x o` to `foo-it`, and you don't like that.

```el
(define-key foo-mode-map (kbd "C-x o") nil)
```

And suppose you want `foo-mode-map` on prefix key `<f9>`:

```el
(define-prefix-command 'foo-mode-map)
(define-key global-map (kbd "<f9>") 'foo-mode-map)
```

Comment: This will also cause that `foo-it` will not be available via `<f9> C-x o`, which might be self-defeating if the goal is to move the keybindings out of the way while remaining accessible through the prefix key.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the mode's keymap directly to move all the bindings under your chosen prefix:

```
(setcdr my-mode-map
  `(keymap (?\C-c keymap (?m keymap . ,(cdr my-mode-map)))))
```